# Fails addItemWithProductID with error: Refusing client without bundle identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, media-library

I am using MPMediaPlaylist method add item with product ID:

```
// Swift
MPMediaPlaylist.addItemWithProductID(_: String, completionHandler: ((NSError?) -> Void)?)

// objective-c
- (void)addItemWithProductID:(NSString *)productID completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSError * __nullable error))completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_3);
```

Item can not be added as it fails with error:

Apr 26 16:37:52 iPhone tccd[110] : Refusing client without bundle identifier (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/Support/medialibraryd)

I want to notice that bundle identifier is set in Xcode. As well I did try to install my app throw TestFlight.

**Why it is failing with error: Refusing client without bundle identifier?**

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I made work around. Before adding track to playlist stored track count. Then adding track with delay around 5 sec. And after that checking is track count increased by one, then track was added.